# How to stop users from manually editing file path in HTML file input control?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a asp.net form with 5 HTML file input controls with runat=server and a submit button. after user selects the files and clicks the submit button, the files are upload in the server.

Problem is the HTML file input controls are editable, and user can edit the path after he has already selected the file from the browse button.

If he enters a invalid file path, the file is not uploaded because it does not exist.

How can I stop users from manually changing the file path? I have tried to make the controls read only, but it disables the browse button also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like having a hidden field and when the user selects the file from browse, it populates to the hidden field as well.  Then when they upload, you either read from the hidden field for your upload or using JS replace the values back to the original control and read from that.

Comment: that will upload the valid file even if the user changed the path to invalid one/or erases the whole path. :-(

Comment: File inputs are read only from JavaScript … and copying their value to a hidden input won't cause the hidden input to upload a file.

Comment: yes it would require some backend code to manage it this way.  You could also try an asynch upload so once the valid file is selected it starts the process rather than waiting for the user to click upload.   This would prevent them from changing the file path.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Write your server side logic to cope with missing uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to have...

You can do like that hiding the control when user select the file
and showing only the path to the user 
in a div 
if he disagree, let him click on a link called Choose Another next to the path div, so when user click Choose another toggle the same div with flushing the previous value

see this fiddle :   http://jsfiddle.net/T2D3X/

Answer (score 0):

While brian's suggestion works (Thank you brian for this), finally we decided to follow the server side handling approach. since in case of invalid file, the file size would be zero, so the response is instant and we do not need to wait till the file is uploaded because in this case there is not file in the first place.

```
//check if file exists

                if (uploadCtrl.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    uploadCtrl.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileNameWithPath);
                    uploadCtrl.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    fileNameWithPath = "invalid";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use these methods:

One before validating: http://jsfiddle.net/T2D3X/1/

One After validating: http://jsfiddle.net/T2D3X/2/

Friend of mine posted the same answer before I have re-modified it.

There are some internal jsfiddle error on second link you can ignore that, i have just added more functionally to check on submit what value exactly you are sending.

Let us know if you find the it helpful ;) 
Thank!